# Replace environment variables in public/manifest.xml

Tags: environment-variables, vite

I have this app built with Vite, that has a `public/manifest.xml` file which contains URLs.

I'd like to make sure that at build time, the `manifest.xml` generated file has entries like `%HOSTNAME%/index.html` replaced with the actual content of the env variable as stated there:

https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#html-env-replacement

For now, it doesn't work.

- Am I doing it wrong?
- Do I have to move the `manifest.xml` file elsewhere?
- Do I need a better env config? Like using the `VITE_` prefix?
- Do I have to write a custom vite plugin to do that? Ain't there one already?

Comment: Share your Vite config, and environment setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default env variable solution only works for JS/TS and HTML, not XML.

There is one solution, but this will **not** work in *dev mode*, it will work fine in *every other mode* where you are actually building (like stage and prod).

Install the following packages:

```
yarn add @types/node path vite-plugin-transform --dev
```

And then you can have a `vite.config.ts` like so:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import transformPlugin from 'vite-plugin-transform';
import { resolve, join } from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    transformPlugin({
      tStart: '%{',
      tEnd: '}%',
      replaceFiles: [resolve(join(__dirname, '/dist/manifest.xml'))],
      replace: {
        HOSTNAME: process.env.HOSTNAME,
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

Now make sure you have your `manifest.xml` in the`public` folder and to use the correct wrapping characters (`%{` and `}%` instead of just `%`, so: `%{HOSTNAME}%` otherwise it will break the regex of the transformer plugin), run `yarn build` and you should have a properly replaced `manifest.xml` in your `dist` folder.